# XLRD rendering the wrong data while iterating the cellls having True/False and Percentage value

Tags: python, xlrd

When Cell contains True it returns 1 and if contain False it returns 0.

Also if 80% are getting rendered as .8

I am confused now do not know where to look up at.

Comment: `xlrd` doesn't "render"; it extracts what it finds in the Excel file.

Comment: Yeah John. Yes i mean the xlrd taking 0 for false and 1 for True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i think the problem is with file . I think you should  check it with the file.

I have the same issue when the xls file with True and False data created using openofffice and libra office return 0 and 1.

I noticed while iterating the file with xlrd and when i create a file microsoft office .. The xlrd was sorking perfectly fine .. so please check it.

Answer (score 3):

Cell objects have three attributes: ctype is an int, value (which depends on ctype) and xf_index. If "formatting_info" is not enabled when the workbook is opened, xf_index will be None. The following table describes the types of cells and how their values are represented in Python.

[image: Check this]

When you get the Boolean value from text file as 0/1 you can do something like

`text = ("FALSE", "TRUE")[bool_value_from_xl]`

xlrd, as documented, returns the actual stored underlying data value, not the result of formatting it.

Comment: Hi avasal, I accept the solution of teh problem but i was more concern about why it is occurring